# Can I save only the print area of Excel 2010 to SharePoint without the scroll bars?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, sharepoint

Basically what I'm trying to do is load my excel spreadsheet into SharePoint without having the scroll bars. (I have disabled the scroll bars in excel itself, but thanks to the un-used space, they are still there.

I have set the print area and tried to 'delete' the remaining white cells around it, but when I save it, the extra white cells in the page show up. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a SharePoint here to test, but try hiding all the rows and columns that are blank.

To hide rows (similar to columns) :
-Select all the rows from the first one blank.
-Right click on the selection (on the title of it)
-click Hide.

More info on hiding and unhiding:
http://spreadsheets.about.com/od/excelformatting/qt/070814_hide.htm
http://www.accountingweb.com/topic/technology/tricks-hiding-and-unhiding-excel-rows-and-columns

Answer (score 0):

I guess your goal is to hide scroll in SharePoint that's related to the **Excel Web Access Web Part**.

If you want to correct this:

1. In the web part properties you can set the size of the web part (in pixels or percent).
2. You can set the number of rows and number of columns that you want to load and show every time you scroll.